# Get input arguments and output of matlab pcode file

Tags: matlab

As you know you can run P-code (from the manual):

> You invoke the resulting P-code file in the same way you invoke the MATLAB .m source file from which it was derived.
> For example, to invoke file myfun.p, type:
>
> [out, out2, ...] = myfun(in1, in2, ...);

At university I need to execute a matplab program which has .p files.
The program has a GUI which works fine but I need to execute it via the command line.

**The problem is that I don't know the input argument types (and number of arguments) and the output types of each .p file, is there any way to find them out?** (I don't want to decode them!)

Best wishes
Leo

P.S.: I alreday googled a lot...

Comment: Thanks, I just tried but unfortunately he did not provide any help description :/

Comment: I did contact the developer but he wants 150€ to send me the full source code which I don't want and he won't help me!

Is there a way to just decode the information I need and not the whole program, or can I use Matlab somehow to give me the information I need?

Comment: Search for the implementations of the `pcode` from the GUI - then document the inputs and outputs that the GUI functions use.  It will be slow and tedious but you will capture how the GUI uses the code so you can replicate...

Comment: Would be a good idea but the gui is also a .p program that I run (everything is a pcode...)

Comment: That is what I did but he would't give me the information and wants me to buy the full source code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to follow the author's suggestion, you have to perform some trial and error reverse engineering on the function (I don't consider decompilation a viable option). Let's suppose we have the following pcoded function:

```
function [a,b] = dosomething(x,y)
    a = x * y;
    b = x + y;
end
```

The first step consists in discovering how many input and output arguments are defined:

```
nargin(@dosomething) % 2
nargout(@dosomething) % 2
```

Now... what you should do is to setup your console command as follows:

```
[v1,v2] = dosomething(...)
```

and start guessing the correct input types. Output types will be given to you once the function can run smoothly until the end of its code. If you have a good knowledge of Matlab common errors, it will be easy for you to come closer and closer to the correct input types. For example, if the following error is thrown:

> Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

you can suppose that a curly braces indexing is being performed on a vector, so the correct type to provide for one of the variables is a cell array (you test it on the first one, then on the other eventually)... and so on. Of course, you can also hope for some custom error messages included in the function by the author that can point you to the right direction... such an espensive function must implement a great exception handling after all, isn't it? ;-)

I also suggest you to start using non-vector inputs (scalar numbers and such). Once the function can run without errors, you can expand the dimensions of the input arguments and see the reaction to test if the function can handle multidimensional variables too.